# react-native-multiselect-view - render containers as "pressed"

Tags: react-native

[react-native-multiselect-view](https://github.com/bgoyal2222/react-native-multiselect-view) is a seemingly simple library.....however I cant find a way to render a container as "pressed" (i.e. active) without physically pressing it.  I want user to make choices and store them in Firebase.....this way when they re-open the app I will fetch choices from Firebase and update UI for their previous selections.  Im guessing I need to change the data array `data={['item1', 'item2']}` to reflect whether item is active or not.....but cant figure out exactly how

```
import MultiSelectView from 'react-native-multiselect-view';

<MultiSelectView
    data={['item1', 'item2']}
    inactiveContainerStyle={{padding:2, borderColor: colorConsts.c3, opacity:0.25, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius:sizeConsts.widgetBorderRadius, backgroundColor:'white'}}
    activeContainerStyle={{padding:2, borderColor: colorConsts.c2, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius:sizeConsts.widgetBorderRadius, backgroundColor:'white'}}
    activeTextStyle={{color:colorConsts.c2}}
    inactiveTextStyle={{color:colorConsts.c3}}
    inactiveIcon={<IconFA name="plus-circle" size={20} style={{color:colorConsts.c3}}/>}
    activeIcon={<IconFA name="minus-circle" size={20} style={{color:colorConsts.c2}}/>}
    onSelectionStatusChange={this._onSelectionStatusChange}
/>
```

Comment: I took a look at the library, you could try to pass to the data prop an array of object like this: [`{value: "item1", checked: true}]`

Answer (score 0):

I emailed author who kindly came right back to me with: "It's not implemented at the moment.  But here the code screenshot where it can be handled. U can raise a PR or fork repo and do it.  If u need me to do it for u let me know.."

I decided instead to write my own and use much of the authors code (below)....I pull user preferences from Firebase....into Redux....into local state

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {sizeConsts, colorConsts} from '../globalConst';
import IconFA from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

//*********************************************************
//REDUX
//*********************************************************
const passStateToProps = state => ({
  arrObjInterests: state.profile.mySelf.arrInterests,
  userId: state.auth.userId,
});

class MyMultiSelectView extends Component {
  //To update the status of any arrInterests object, run a map on the array and check for some unique value of each object,
  //in case of condition=true, return the new object with updated value, else same object.
  _onPress = (label, oldValue) => {
    //FIRST UPDATE STATE FOR QUICK UI RESPONSE
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        //map through prevState interests array and return each object same as you saw it
        //.....unless its a match in which case you update the value
        arrInterests: prevState.arrInterests.map(obj =>
          obj.label === label ? {...obj, value: !oldValue} : obj,
        ),
      }),
      () => {
        //NEXT UPDATE FBS WITH UPDATED STATE
        //prettier-ignore
        database().ref('/profiles/users/' + this.props.userId + '/arrInterests').set(this.state.arrInterests);
      },
    );
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //populate state with interests array arrInterests from Redux arrObjInterests
    this.state = {
      arrInterests: this.props.arrObjInterests,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //prettier-ignore
      <View
        style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: 1, padding: 15}}>
        {/* map through interests array and create TouchableOpacity for each */}
        {this.state.arrInterests.map((item, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => {
            this._onPress(item.label, item.value);
          }}>
            <View style={!item.value ? [styles.container, {borderColor: colorConsts.c3, opacity:0.25}] : [styles.container, {borderColor: colorConsts.c2}]}>
              <Text style={!item.value ? [styles.text, {color:colorConsts.c3}] : [styles.text, {color:colorConsts.c2}]}>{item.label}</Text>
              {!item.value ? <IconFA name="plus-circle" size={20} style={[styles.icon, {color:colorConsts.c3}]}/> : <IconFA name="minus-circle" size={20} style={[styles.icon, {color:colorConsts.c2}]}/>}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingVertical: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: sizeConsts.widgetBorderRadius,
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'black',
    marginRight: 6,
  },
  icon: {
    width: 20,
    marginRight: 2,
  },
});

export default connect(
  passStateToProps,
  null,
)(MyMultiSelectView);
```